# Extract strings that follow changing time strings

Tags: python, regex

So I've been trying to extract the strings that follow the "dot" character in the text file, but only for lines that follow the pattern as below, that is, after the date and time:

09 May 2018 10:37AM • 6PR, Perth (Mornings)

The problem is for each of those lines, the date and time would change so the only common pattern is that there would be AM or PM right before the "dot".

However, if I search for "AM" or "PM" it wouldn't recognize the lines because the "AM" and "PM" are attached to the time.

This is my current code:

> ```
> for i,s in enumerate(open(file)):
>     for words in ['PM','AM']:
>       if re.findall(r'\b' + words + r'\b', s):
>         source=s.split('•')[0]
> ```

Any idea how to get around this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Since the changing date time won't change the length of given time string format. How about simply using the string containing check with: `if 'AM •' in s or 'PM •' in s: dt = s[:19]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your regex is the problem here.

```
for i, s in enumerate(open(file)):
    if re.findall(r'\d{2}[AP]M', s):
        source = s.split('•')[0]

# 09 May 2018 10:37AM
```

Comment: @NguyenTuongBaoKim Use `r'\d{2}[AP]M'` then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated the code to include that refactor, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extract the datetime try using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "09 May 2018 10:37AM • 6PR, Perth (Mornings)"
m = re.search("(?P<datetime>\d{2}\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+\d{4}\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}(AM|PM))", s)
if m:
    print m.group("datetime")
```

**Output:**

```
09 May 2018 10:37AM
```